# Determine capacity of batteries for solar installation

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, capacity

I have four 420 Ah 6 volt batteries wired in series and then parallel.

What is the capacity of the combined four?

Comment: Define "in series and then parallel." There is a schematic diagram tool available, just edit your question and click the schematic editor button.

Comment: Four times the capacity of a single battery.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have two batteries in series to make 12 V, and two such pairs in parallel, you will have 840 Ah total at 12 V.

With batteries in series, the Ah rating is unchanged. With batteries in parallel, the Ah ratings add.

The Ah rating is only a partial measure of the energy in the battery, as it ignores the voltage.

Comment: You had a mistake where you wrote "series" twice instead of "series" then "parallel". I took the liberty of editing it for you.

Comment: Please note: AH = amperehenry. Ah = amperehour.